# Passing types that do not have a constructor as arguments

Tags: c#

I've been playing with different `System.Security.Cryptography` hash functions to just know about the key length of different hashing systems. To do that I thought about writing a method that returned the key size based on an argument. (returning key sizes are not the problem, that's what made me ask the question)

I though about this :

```
// I know I could use the interface as the type of T but let's define it as dynamic for now 
public static Byte[] Size(dynamic T) {

    return T.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hello"));
}
```

now, since these hash functions (Hash generation types) do not have a constructor, I cannot use this method like

```
 Size(new MD5()); // This is wrong coz there is no constructor
```

and I can't  pass the type just like:

```
Size(MD5); // Error
```

In case I'd like to pass these kind of type directly as an argument without declaring them first and passing them like `MD5 md5` and `Size(md5)`, what exactly do I have to do.
I'm just curious if that is possible at all.

Comment: This site helped me out with that. http://www.dijksterhuis.org/creating-salted-hash-values-in-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the the help of reflection

```
var size = Size<MD5>();
```

---

```
public static Byte[] Size<T>()
{
    dynamic hashFxn = typeof(T).InvokeMember("Create",BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,null,null);
    return hashFxn.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hello"));
}
```

Comment: Outstanding, yeah that's exactly what I meant. Leaned something today, thanks, will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create instance of `MD5` class directly, because it's marked as abstract. Instead, you should create instance of a class that inherits `MD5`.

There are two options, `MD5Cng` or `MD5CryptoServiceProvider`, within `System.Security.Cryptography`.

Now, you can pass `Size(new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())`, but it will fail at runtime, because there is no instance `Create` method exposed by `MD5` or `MD5CryptoServiceProvider`.

Modify your method to take `HashAlgorithm` instead of `dynamic` and remove `Create` method call:

```
public static Byte[] Size(HashAlgorithm T) {

    return T.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hello"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MD5` is an abstract class so you need to provide a concrete subclass. You could do:

```
public static byte[] Size<T>() where T : HashAlgorithm, new()
{
    using (var hash = new T())
    {
        return hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hello"));
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
var bytes = Size<MD5CryptoServiceProvider>();
```